# force:recordData gives unsupported entity error for a newly created Business Platform Object BoatReview

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-data-service, superbadges, force-recorddata, data-service

I want to use **force:recordData** component for BoatReview's addReview functionality. But I am getting this error "This entity is not currently supported by force:recordData." What else I need to do as per new entity setting to make it available for force component. I am new to this, went through existing questions but still issue is not resolved.

Answer (score 0):

In my case BoatReview is not a custom object (Its a internal entity), so by default It was not enabled for LDS. To enable that I had to follow few steps and change core files. Those who are struggling with issue and are internal user, please follow my solution at internal thread on Slack. Just search this issue you will find the answer.